# Slow Cordova mobile app, using ReactJS

Tags: cordova, meteor, reactjs

Trying to figure out how to speed up a Cordova app.

I built a Cordova app using ReactJS, approx 2600 LOC of my own React code, about 1500 lines of CSS for styling. approx 20 screens. I don't have any backend hooked up, right now just client views.

I tested this using pure Cordova, and also within MeteorJS (and it's Cordova build tools). Same result, my app is much slower that expected, even when showing React Components with zero images, just text, again not touching a server.

I've got around 8GB of images, in the app, but wouldn't expect them to slow down React components that don't even use images.

Running on Samsung Galaxy S5
Android v4.4.2

Comment: If you are using React not optimally, it may happen that your components are being re-rendered multiple times (when only one re-render is necessary). Try logging some info message on every render so you get some idea what and when gets re-rendered. Of course, without more info, this is just a wild guess.

Comment: You are right that I'm rendering 6 views/Components that don't need refreshing (when I open my popup menu). I'll have to fix that to see if it solves this performance issue. I also have this warning, not sure how this affects performance: `Warning: bind(): You are binding a component method to the component. React does this for you automatically in a high-performance way, so you can safely remove this call.`

Comment: Well, if you do the binding manually, you probably waste a few cycles here, however, this operation should be quite fast. Therefore, I doubt this is the main reason, why your app is slow.

Comment: Do I need to "touch" enable my React app/components, for mobile?